# Simple ngRoute not working

Tags: angularjs, controller, routes, ngroute

Why this code not works?

```
angular.module('routers', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  console.log('1. routes loaded!');

  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      controller: 'HomeController'
    })

    .when('/about', {
      controller: 'AboutController'
    });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}])

.controller('HomeController', function () {
  console.log('2. HomeController loaded!');
})

.controller('AboutController', function () {
  console.log('3. AboutController loaded!');
});
```

When the page is loaded, the **1. routes loaded!** log appears perfectly but the **2. HomeController...** log not.
when I type **localhost:8000/about** in my browse, I receive the following return:

> Cannot GET /about

What does this simple code not works?

Comment: That's not how ngRoute works.  ngRoute isn't watching your address bar.  ngRoute only works in concert with the $location service, e.g. $location.path("/about");

Comment: add a template 
`$routeProvider.when('/', {
             controller: 'HomeController',
             template: '<div>Home Loaded</div>
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Here are the changes,

```
var app = angular.module("app", ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
  when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    controllerAs: 'homeCtrl'
  }).
  when('/about', {
    templateUrl: 'about.html',
    controller: 'AboutController',
    controllerAs: 'AboutCtrl'
  });
}])

app.controller('HomeController', function () {
  console.log('2. HomeController loaded!');
})

app.controller('AboutController', function () {
  console.log('3. AboutController loaded!');
});
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/2eaVuxbyp8ftlaawpYmz?p=preview)**

Comment: OP states that he expects to enter route path in the *browser* and have it display the angular resource.  How is this providing the desired outcome?